# Can I use an array in findcontrol?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello I have a `DataList` that has four lables and they all end with a number 1-4. In my code behind I have a for loop and an array  that I want to set the labels of the `Datalist` with.

```
for (int x = 0; x< cartreciept.Items.Count; x++)
{
    DataListItem item = cartreceipt.Items[x];
    string catalogtype = ("select CatalogType From SC Where OrNum=" + OrNum)

    if (catalogtype="TC")
    {    
         ((Panel)item.FindControl("pnlIprintInfo")).Visible = true;
         string scRID = ("Select SCRID From SC Where OrNum =" + OrNum

        for(int y = 1; y<5; y++)
        {
              string lT[y] = (Select LineText From table Where SCartRD =" + scRID + " AND LN=" + y)

              ((Label)item.FindControl("lbl[y]")).text = lT[y];
        }
     }
}
```

So would the `((Label)item.FindControl("lbl[y]"))` work? most of this code is just pseudo code until I figure the details out. If you need to know anything else I can provide what needs to be known, I am open to other suggestions as well. Thank you to any one who can offer some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code - based on `string.Format("....{0}",arguments)`

```
var control = (Label)item.FindControl(string.Format("lbl{0}",y));
```

I suggest you to use `DataList.ItemDataBound`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemdatabound.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the help, I completly over looked something so simple